# What to do if the data does not reach?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I have a page `index.vue`
on this page I have the following code

```
<nuxt-link :to="'/user/'+userid">Go to user</nuxt-link>
```

We go to the user
to the page `user/_id.vue`

On this page I am making a request using Graphql

```
export default {
  apollo: {
    user: {
      prefetch: true,
      query: user,
      variables() {
        return {
          id: this.$route.params.id
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

```
query user($id: Int) {
  user(where: {id: {_eq: $id}}) {
    name
  }
}
```

If you click on the button on this page, then it returns to me `undefined`

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.users) // return undefined
  },
```

Sorry for my English How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and log your data via fetch.

```
export default {

data(){
    return {
        mydata: [],
        query: ''
    }
},
fetch() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.users);
  },
}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/

I'm sure there is another way to log data/data changes by using watchLoading/errorHandler in your apollo module setup but I could not get it to function - so I am using fetch.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module